# Capitlising first letter in pandas dataframe column, whilst retaining other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Problem:**

Hi, I'm trying to capitalise the first column's first word in each row in a pandas dataframe, when I try to do this I either delete the other rows in the dataframe, or the first words don't end up being capitalised.

**Current code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')

df2 = df1.replace('_', ' ', regex=True)

df2.Species.str.capitalize()

df2.to_csv('bar.csv',index=False)
```

**Desired output:**

Retaining the replacement made in df2, changing underscore to whitespace, but also capitalising the first word in the newly replaced df2, then saving to csv.

```
+-----------------------------+--------+-----+-----------+
|           Species           |   ID   | OGT |    DB     |
+-----------------------------+--------+-----+-----------+
| Streptomyces cirratus       |  68187 |  28 | DSMZ      |
| Halogeometricum borinquense |  60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ |
| Sphingobium japonicum       | 332056 |  28 | DSMZ      |
+-----------------------------+--------+-----+-----------+
```

**Subset of Input CSV:**

```
+-----------------------------+--------+-----+-----------+
|           Species           |   ID   | OGT |    DB     |
+-----------------------------+--------+-----+-----------+
| streptomyces_cirratus       |  68187 |  28 | DSMZ      |
| halogeometricum_borinquense |  60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ |
| sphingobium_japonicum       | 332056 |  28 | DSMZ      |
+-----------------------------+--------+-----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need assign back output:

```
df2.Species = df2.Species.str.capitalize()
```

Or if need replace only column `Species`:

```
df1.Species = df1.Species.replace('_', ' ', regex=True).str.capitalize()
df1.to_csv('bar.csv',index=False)
```